# Failed to create provisioning profile ( xcode 14.1 )

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, xcode14

I want to publish my flutter app to AppStore and I am faced with these two errors

1. Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Select a device run destination to have Xcode register it.
2. No profiles for 'com.web.editor' were found. Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.web.editor'.

how can we solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to register your app in appstoreconnect. There you can create the required provisioning profile.

Comment: i have created the profile, it still give me this message